# Deploying Sinatra app on Dreamhost/Passenger with custom gems

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubygems, dreamhost, pony

I've got a Sinatra app that I'm trying to run on Dreamhost that makes use of pony to send email. In order to get the application up and running at the very beginning (before adding pony), I had to `gem unpack rack` and `gem unpack sinatra` into the vendor/ directory, so this was my config.ru:

```
require 'vendor/rack/lib/rack'
require 'vendor/sinatra/lib/sinatra'

set :run, false
set :environment, :production
set :views, "views"

require 'public/myapp.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

I have already done `gem install pony` and `gem unpack pony` (into vendor/). Afterwards, I tried adding `require 'vendor/sinatra/lib/pony'` to config.ru only to have Passenger complain about pony's *dependencies* (mime-types, tmail) not being found either!

There **has** to be a better way to use other gems and tone down those long, ugly, redundant `requires`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend creating your own gem path "somewhere" then adding it in your `config.ru`
like:

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = xxx
Gem.clear_paths
```

then install your gems into that

Comment: Yes! Using that info I went and found http://www.edschmalzle.com/2009/06/29/deploying-sinatra-with-passenger-on-dreamhost/ and got it running. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Install Ruby gems on dreamhost

https://c.kat.pe/installing-ruby-gems-on-dreamhost

Change config.ru (works for Sinatra 1.0)

require 'rubygems'

require 'vendor/sinatra/lib/sinatra.rb'

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/home/username/.gems'
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths

disable :run, :reload

set :environment, :production

require 'yourapp'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Hope it helps someone.

I am using pony and a lot of other gems for my Sinatra. It should work well for you too. It's just those two lines (GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH) you have to add on your config.

Answer (score 1):

It took me ages to find that you can simply use "gem install sinatra" and gem will figure out (because the system directories are read-only) that you will need to use a local gem install directory.  As of now, there seems to be no need to set any special environment at all.  It figures out to use $HOME/.gem as the local gem path and everything just works.  No need for require 'vendor/stuff' at all.  I did find I had to add $HOME/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin to my path in order to execute binaries installed by gems.

Here's my config.ru (for Dreamhost)

```
## Passenger should set RACK_ENV for Sinatra
require 'test'
set :environment, :development
run Sinatra::Application
```

Later edit: This is all well and fine, but there remains the issue that [Passenger can't find my gems when the job initially starts up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116837/sinatra-on-passenger-always-fails-on-first-attempt/).

Answer (score 0):

My config.ru is just simple as:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'vendor/sinatra/lib/sinatra.rb'
require 'app.rb'
```

and app.rb head:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'haml'
require 'ostruct'
require 'date'
require 'pp'

module FlytoFB
    log = File.new("sinatra.log", "a")
    STDOUT.reopen(log)
    STDERR.reopen(log)

    configure do

            enable :logging, :dump_errors
            set :app_file, __FILE__
            set :reload, true
            set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
            set :environment, :production
            set :env, :production
            set :run, false

            set :raise_errors, true
      set :public, 'public'

            error do
                    e = request.env['sinatra.error']
                    puts e.to_s
                    puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
                    "Application Error!"
            end

            not_found do
              "Page not found!"
      end
```